# libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.bundle” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I'm currently attempting to train my own model using ML-Agents and Unity. I launched the 3DBall project, and it functions correctly when I start it with a pre-trained model. However, when I try to train my own model with ML-Agents, I encounter the following error: "libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.bundle” cannot be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. I'm struggling to identify the source of this issue.

I've already tried reinstalling grpcio, but unfortunately, that didn't resolve the problem. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found an answer I needed to deactivated gatekeeper here's the command to activate:

```bash
sudo spctl --master-disable and to enable sudo spctl --master-enable
```